# Is it possible to get the SQL query causing a Spring DataAccessException?

Tags: spring, logging, jdbctemplate

I have an application that uses a JdbcTemplate to perform queries on a MySQL database. If the JdbcTemplate ever throws an org.springframework.dao.DataAccessException, it logs the exception's stack trace. However, I'd also like to include the SQL query that caused the exception to be thrown. Is there an easy way to do this that doesn't involve writing custom error messages for every place JdbcTemplate is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only intend to log SQL statements during an exception, you might have to write your own custom subclass of `JdbcTemplate` and alter the logging preconditions as seen in the source code at [Github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jdbc/src/main/java/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java).

If that is not the case, you may consider the following.

From the [Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/data-access.html), All SQL Statements are logged at DEBUG level.

> All SQL issued by this class is logged at the DEBUG level under the category corresponding to the fully qualified class name of the template instance (typically JdbcTemplate, but it may be different if you are using a custom subclass of the JdbcTemplate class).

You make also change the Jdbc url by setting `profileSQL` to `true` to trace the SQL.

[MySQl Connection Reference Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Comment: I didn't know they were DEBUG logged, thank you for that :)

Comment: No problem mate, do mark this as answer if it's helpful. Cheers.